# How can I create and run SikuliX scripts on MacOS?

Tags: macos, automation, ui-automation, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I'm trying to use Sikuli on MacOS to do some automation. I've downloaded the SikuliX IDE 2.0.4 from [here](https://raiman.github.io/SikuliX1/downloads.html), and Jython 2.7.2 from [here](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/wiki/How-to-make-Jython-ready-in-the-IDE), and put the two of them in the same directory as per instructions in the docs.

I'm running MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 and this is the Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_281" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

I'm able to open the SikuliX IDE, however when I click on the "Take Screenshot" button all applications are minimized, including the ones I want to take a screenshot of, and that happens even if I open the application that I want to automate and use the SikuliX IDE shortcut to take a screenshot.

When this happens only the SikuliX menu bar, background and docker are visible. And even then, if I try to take a screenshot of a icon in the docker the image that opens up on the SikuliX IDE contains only the background, as if the docker is transparent.

I tried to take a screenshot using MacOS's default tools, but in this case when I try to run an instruction as simple as `click()` the script crashes.

This is the output of an attempt to click on the Finder icon in the docker:

[image]

```
[error] script [ create_new_folder ] stopped with error in line 1
[error] FindFailed ( finder_icon.png: (86x78) in R[0,0 1680x1050]@S(0) )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
1: main (  <module> )     click("finder_icon.png")
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

I wasn't able to find much stuff about SikuliX on MacOS. Any suggestions on how I might be able to take screenshots and automate things on MacOS with SikuliX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason behind: in the standard macOS now blocks taking screenshots.

Solution: This has to be allowed in the Prefs -> Security&Privacy -> Privacy -> ScreenRecording.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed the problem with the IDE. My endgoal is to be able to modify some C# wrappers and try to run some instructions via command line. Do you know wich artifact should I use to achieve this on MacOS? On sikuliapi 2.0.4 I always get "SikuliX API: nothing to do" I can ask a new question if you prefer. Thank you anyway, and awesome work with Sikuli! : )

Comment: You can run sikuli script via command line with -r option